# Better way to generate random number that is not already used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to generate a random 9 digit number that is not already used.

This is the way I currently have and it's working perfectly, but maybe this won't be too great when the table grows:

```
while true
    random_number = 9.times.map{rand(9)}.join
    found = Document.find_by(dfe_number: random_number)
    return random_number if found.nil?
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or a faster way? Thank you all.

Comment: In general, if you add date/time of the generation to the output number it will be good, but... you  don't have enough space with only 9 digits :(

Comment: @J_P Thanks for the suggestion, maybe hour+minutes+day + 3 random numbers would work better, just to be more safe...

Comment: "Better" in what way? "Faster" than what? I had a very similar situation just this past week and went with (essentially) the approach you have. Only, I used SecureRandom to generate my number instead of rolling my own. And, I put it in an AR call_back. But, essentially the same.

Comment: @jvillian I guess this is one of the better ways. "Better and/or Faster" I think I was hoping to see some ruby on rails magic or something, you never know xD

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that you want to save new instances of `Document` each with a unique, random `dfe_number`.
In this case you should take an "optimistic" approach by assuming a collision is very improbable.

Therefore you should:

1. define a DB unique constraint on `documents.dfe_number`
2. get a new random `dfe_number` - using your method or `'%09d' % rand(10 ** 9)`
3. try to insert the new instance
4. catch any `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` and retry

P.S.: You should make sure that the expected number of `Document` instances is orders of magnitude smaller than 10 ** 10 or, if that cannot be guaranteed, use some more digits.

Comment: I didn't post in the question to make it more simple, but dfe_number cant be unique, I can have the same dfe_number for multiple companies. If I went with your way, I'd have to validate uniqueness in multiple fields...

Comment: Your approach needs at least 2 SQL queries, one for checking, one (I assume) for inserting. You could bring this down to 1 if you could somehow create a DB unique index that prevents inserting when required uniqueness is violated, only then trying another random number. You would have to give more details on your requirements, though.

Comment: The problem is, I have to do some other processing after I generated the number, so I think there isn't too much of a choice here. I asked the question to see if I could improve the loop somehow, or see if it had a faster way...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Is two-column uniqueness DB index not possible in your case? I imagined that perhaps you have another column like `company_id` alongside `dfe_number` in the `Documents` table? If you are using a multi-threaded Rails server like puma, or multi-process, or have multiple application servers, then it's best to add uniqueness index if this `dfe_number` is really really important to be unique.